# Camera start to freak out when clamping to angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im building a first person controller in unity and im trying to make it so the camera tracks mouse location so the player could look around but when i try and block the player from getting the camera upside down the camra starts to shake and it messes the rotation of the camera

```
// Get Axis
float mouseY = Input.GetAxis(mouseYInputName) * mouseSensitivity * 
Time.deltaTime;
// Check if past limit
clampX += mouseY;
if (Mathf.Abs(clampX) < 90f) {
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);
}
else {
    Vector3 eulerRotation = -transform.eulerAngles;
    eulerRotation.x = (clampX > 90f ? 270f : 90f);
    transform.eulerAngles = eulerRotation;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code.

First, you negative the rotation when assigning it to your vector (`-transform.eulerAngles`) but then just re-assign the modified vector to the transform. This will have the effect of flipping the Y and Z axis rotations every frame.

Additionally, the clamping itself looks a bit off. Right now, when the rotation is moved past 90°, it is snapped to 270° instantly, and when it's moved past -90°, it is snapped to 90° instead.

Another issue:
With your current code, if the player keeps moving the mouse after clamping has already started, the `clampX` variable is still being increased. Thus when the player starts moving the mouse in the other direction, they have to get the `clampX` value back into acceptable values again before the camera even starts moving.

Here's an approach to clamping that hopefully doesn't have those issues:

```cs
clampX += mouseY;
if (Mathf.Abs(clampX) < 90f) {
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * mouseY);
}
else {
    if (clampX > 90f) clampX = 90f;
    else if (clampX < -90f) clampX = -90f;

    Vector3 eulerRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
    eulerRotation.x = clampX;
    transform.eulerAngles = eulerRotation;
}
```

(I also replaced `Vector3.left` with `Vector3.right`, since that's positive X in Unity.)

Comment: so i just need to remove the minus when getting the eulerAngles? and what do you mean by clamping the clampX variable?

Comment: @nivshalom I added some explanation and more example code for what I meant. I also noticed an additional small issue so I included that as well. Hope this helps!